# faster evaluation calls of a function

Tags: python, performance, function, numpy, optimization

I have a function that needs to be evaluated at least 1e6 times. It only requires two arrays as input.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

res = np.random.rand(0,1,1000)
f1 = lambda r, sig: -0.5*(np.sum(2*np.log(sig) + np.log(2*np.pi) + (r/sig)**2))
```

Currently,

```
%timeit f1(res,np.sqrt(res))
```

clocks in at 26 usec. Is there any means I can have faster evaluation calls/execution time?

Any means will do; e.g. not using lambda function, using native math instead of numpy, or any tricks involving manipulation of equation using faster math operation implemented in python.

EDIT:

I made a silly mistake of producing an empty `res` array. So it should be

```
res=np.random.rand(1000)
```

Also the second array `np.sqrt(res)` is actually independent from `res` and typically consists of values much smaller than `res` but I used `sqrt(res)` just for illustration.

So rewriting the code more clearly

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

res1 = np.random.rand(1000)
res2 = np.sqrt(res) #not true in general but res2<res1
f1 = lambda r, sig: -0.5*(np.sum(2*np.log(sig) + np.log(2*np.pi) + (r/sig)**2))
```

And now `%f1(res1,res2)` clocks in at 60 usec in my machine.

Comment: is it possible to use a multithreading solution for your case?

Comment: Multithreading will not speed up python calculations due to the Global Interpreter Lock. OP may be able to vectorize the calculation or may be able to use _multiprocessing_ depending on the size of the data to be crunched

Comment: I really think this should be tagged with "numpy" to give the chance for a vectorized approach but I'm not clear whether your question demands a python approach with lambda functions. Your current use of numpy is superfluous, you could do this with `math`

Comment: Using sum instead of np.sum gives a slight improvement from 26usec to 16 usec.

Comment: @JPdL I think it would do no harm if you could clarify two points. 1) Your input array `res` is empty. Is that intentional? 2) Will it be true in general that `sig=sqrt(r)`? Thanks!

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake. I corrected it and added more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the most expensive thing are all that `log`s, and those you can save (i.e. call once instead of `sig.size` - in this example = 1000 - times). The underlying identity is `log(a) + log(b) = log(a*b)`. Gives me a speedup by  a factor of three.

Btw. I changed `random.rand(0, 1, 1000)` which produces an empty array to `random.rand(1000)`. Also I take it `sig=sqrt(res)` is not a general assumption, so I didn't try and exploit that.

I do a few other optimizations but their effect is nowhere near as massive as getting rid of the `log`s. 1) precompute `log(2*pi)` 2) use `np.dot` for the last term.

### Update:

As @JPdL points out this method is vulnerable to over- and underflow. One can trade various amounts of performance to guard against that using chunking, see `f4. f5. f6` below.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

res = np.random.rand(1000)
f1 = lambda r, sig: -0.5*(np.sum(2*np.log(sig) + np.log(2*np.pi) + (r/sig)**2)) 

def f2(r, sig):
    return -0.5*(np.sum(2*np.log(sig) + np.log(2*np.pi) + (r/sig)**2))

# gung ho
def f3(r, sig, precomp=np.log(2*np.pi)):
    rs = r/sig
    return -np.log(np.prod(sig)) - 0.5*(r.size * precomp + np.dot(rs, rs))

# chunk and hope for the best
def f4(r, sig, chnk=32, precomp=np.log(2*np.pi)):
    rs = r/sig
    sumlogsig = np.log(np.multiply.reduceat(sig, np.arange(0, len(r), chnk))).sum()
    return -sumlogsig - 0.5*(r.size * precomp + np.dot(rs, rs))

# chunk and check for extreme values
def f5(r, sig, chnk=32,
       precomp=np.log(2*np.pi), precomp2=np.exp([-8, 8])):
    rs = r/sig
    bad = np.where((sig<precomp2[0]) | (sig>precomp2[1]))[0]
    sumlogsig = np.log(sig[bad]).sum()
    keep = sig[bad]
    sig[bad] = 1
    sumlogsig += np.log(np.multiply.reduceat(sig, np.arange(0, len(r), chnk))).sum()
    sig[bad] = keep
    return -sumlogsig - 0.5*(r.size * precomp + np.dot(rs, rs))

# chunk and try to be extra clever
def f6(r, sig, chnk=512,
       precomp=np.log(2*np.pi), precomp2=np.exp(np.arange(-18, 19))):
    binidx = np.digitize(sig, precomp2[1::2])<<1
    rs = r/sig
    sig = sig*precomp2[36 - binidx]
    bad = np.where((binidx==0) | (binidx==36))[0]
    sumlogsig = binidx.sum() - 18*r.size + np.log(sig[bad]).sum()
    sig[bad] = 1
    sumlogsig += np.log(np.multiply.reduceat(sig, np.arange(0, len(r), chnk))).sum()
    return -sumlogsig - 0.5*(r.size * precomp + np.dot(rs, rs))

from timeit import timeit
sr = np.sqrt(res)
print(timeit('f1(res,sr)', number=100, globals={'res':res, 'np':np, 'sr':sr, 'f1':f1}))
print(timeit('f2(res,sr)', number=100, globals={'res':res, 'np':np, 'sr':sr, 'f2':f2}))
print(timeit('f3(res,sr)', number=100, globals={'res':res, 'np':np, 'sr':sr, 'f3':f3}))
print(timeit('f4(res,sr)', number=100, globals={'res':res, 'np':np, 'sr':sr, 'f4':f4}))
print(timeit('f5(res,sr)', number=100, globals={'res':res, 'np':np, 'sr':sr, 'f5':f5}))
print(timeit('f6(res,sr)', number=100, globals={'res':res, 'np':np, 'sr':sr, 'f6':f6}))
print(f1(res,np.sqrt(res)))
print(f2(res,np.sqrt(res)))
print(f3(res,np.sqrt(res)))
print(f4(res,np.sqrt(res)))
print(f5(res,np.sqrt(res)))
print(f6(res,np.sqrt(res)))
```

Sample output:

```
0.004246247990522534
0.00418912700843066
0.0011273059935774654
0.0013386670034378767
0.0022679700050503016
0.004274581006029621
-662.250886322
-662.250886322
-662.250886322
-662.250886322
-662.250886322
-662.250886322
```

Comment: Paul's answer is currently the fastest, at least twice as fast as the other implementations. When I use your function however, I get an overflow in `np.prod(sig)` as you can see by simply checking output of `np.prod(np.random.rand(1000))` is 0.

Comment: @JPdL no, I think the square root keeps it just representable (effectively `rand(500)`), how else would it be able to give the right result. That said, you are, of course, right that over- or underflow are a concern here. Can you say anything about the values you expect? Perhaps one could balance it (for example with 2pi) or at least chunk it?

Comment: @JPdL thanks for accepting my answer even though I feel in its then state it didn't fully deserve it. I've now added a bit of chunking to address your valid concerns.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, `f1` the way you've defined gives me:

> 10000 loops, best of 3: 20.9 µs per loop

A simple optimisation to avoid computing `np.log(2*np.pi)` every the time:

```
log2pi = np.log(2*np.pi)
f2 = lambda r, sig: -0.5*(np.sum(2*np.log(sig) + log2pi + (r/sig)**2))
```

which reduces my `timeit` output in approximately 15%:

> 100000 loops, best of 3: 17.8 µs per loop

Also, it is usually faster to compute `x*x` than `x**2`. With this approach, you can avoid the `2*` operation too.

```
def f3(r, sig):
   sig2 = sig * sig
   return -0.5*(np.sum(np.log(sig2) + log2pi + (r*r/sig2)))
```

> 100000 loops, best of 3: 15 µs per loop

Furthermore, depending on how often you are calling this function with arguments `res, np.sqrt(res)`, you could definitely consider simplifying it to:

```
f4 = lambda a: -0.5*np.sum(np.log(a) + log2pi + a)
```

You can check that `f4(res) == f1(res, np.sqrt(res))` and that it goes significantly faster too (around 44%).

> 100000 loops, best of 3: 11.7 µs per loop

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer but this is based on the assumption that the second input is always np.sqrt(res) which in general not true. I made this point explicit in the edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can skip `np.sum()`, because you call it on a single argument that is obtained by applying `+` operator. Besides, `np.log(2*np.pi)` is constant and won't depend on lambda args, so you can calculate it outside lambda and reuse. Also, that probably won't change much, but check whether `a**2` is faster or slower than `a*a`; if the latter is faster, calculate `d = r/sig` once and use `d*d` instead of `(r/sig)**2`. You can also check whether `0.5*x` is faster or slower than `x/2.0`. This aint much, but it may give you speedup of an usec or two.

And now, some math.
After suggestions above you get:

```
log_of_pi = np.log(2*np.pi)
f1 = lambda r, sig: -0.5*(2*np.log(sig) + log_of_pi + (r/sig)**2))
f1(res,np.sqrt(res))
```

So basically, you calculate:

```
c1*(2*log(sqrt(r)) + c2 + (r/sqrt(r))**2)
```

First of all:

```
log(sqrt(r)) = log(r**(1/2)) = 1/2*log(r)
```

Also:

```
(r/sqrt(r))**2 = sqrt(r)**2 = abs(r)
```

So basically, you're trying to calculate:

```
c1*(2*log(sqrt(r)) + c2 + (r/sqrt(r))**2) = c1*(2*1/2*log(r) + c2 + abs(r)) = c1*(log(r) + c2 + abs(r))
```

So, you can skip expensive square of division (last part of sum) and calculating square root of `r` (done before calling `f1`).

Of course that was done assuming that you'll always use `sqrt(r)` as `sig`.

PS. Respect to grovina, who [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47367334/1219585) with the same train of thoughts 15 seconds before me, and provided measurements too. Would you want to accept my answer, accept the other one, as it is more complete.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing implicit copies with your lambda. You can gain a performance boost by using in-place variants of your function where possible. http://ipython-books.github.io/featured-01/

```
def f2(r, sig):
   x = np.log(sig)
   x *= 2  # in-place operation

   x += np.log(2*np.pi)  # in-place operation

   y = r / sig
   y **= 2  # in-place operation

   x += y  # in-place operation

   return -0.5 * x.sum()
```

Also, check the output of

```
import numpy.distutils.system_info as sysinfo
sysinfo.show_all()

...

openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

If blas, lapack and atlas are `NOT AVAILABLE` then you are not getting the most out of numpy. Not by a long shot. These libraries enable numpy to use `SIMD` operations (Single Instruction Multiple Data -- a form of parallelisation).